# Image taking too long to load in layout?

Tags: android, xml, imageview, android-imageview

I am using `ImageView` to make a 1.3 MB image as background for an activity. The activity has another smaller image (the logo) and 3 buttons. There is nothing else in that activity. Now this activity takes upto 9 seconds to display. Till then the app shows a black screen. When I removed the ImageView with the 1.3 MB image, the activity loads instantly. So is this normal for ImageView to take so long to load up an image? How can I reduce this time?

Comment: use image of lower size as much as possible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a few options, but first you must ask *why am I loading such a large bitmap?*

**Make the file smaller**

As @laalto says, adjust the dimensions of the image and make it smaller. Probably the fastest and easiest option. As I can't see the image I can't say if this will make it look any different to the user if the resolution is smaller.

**Downsample the Image**

There are plenty of posts on downsampling large images to avoid `outofmemory` errors. [Here](http://blog.androidquery.com/2011/05/down-sample-images-to-avoid-out-of.html) is a good example from the AndroidQuery team, who in there own right have built a useful [library](https://code.google.com/p/android-query/) that includes this sort of functionality. This is also included in the post.

You could either use their library, use their post (or similar) to write some code or you could use the excellent [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) library from Square, although it might be overkill.

**If there is a repeating background...**

You have not provided the image, but if it repeats you could create a tile instead, then provide this as a resource.

So for an example you could create a new XML file called background_repeat.xml that contains

```
<bitmap
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:src="@drawable/tile"
android:tileMode="repeat"
android:dither="true" />
```

where `tile` is the much much smaller image that you want to repeat.

Comment: OK I cropped the image and its size now is 360KB (resolution is 1501*2200), but still its taking way too long (4 seconds). Any other suggestions you got? Thanks.

Comment: Try for speed to use AQuery, just drop the jar in and use the post I linked to. Downsample the image. IF it works decide if you want to write your own code or keep using AQuery or Picasso etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's normal. The image has to be decoded and scaled. It takes both processing time and memory. Memory handling triggers garbage collection every now and then, slowing the process even further. Use a profiler to find out exactly where the time is spent.

Make the image dimensions smaller to make the decoding go faster and consume less memory.

Comment: I really don't want to lose the resolution of the image if possible. Are there any external libraries which allow loading of the image faster?

Answer (score 0):

You can use android:background to set uo a background from drawable resources. And also you can do this on the root element of your xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_layout"
    android:background="@drawable/navigation_bg"/>
```